# Laptop says "GRUB" when trying to boot from bootable USB stick

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, usb-drive

I flashed Kubuntu onto my USB stick and tried to boot from it on my HP Pavilon dv7. Whenever I do that it only shows the word "GRUB" in the upper left corner and does nothing else. It's not a console or anything. I cannot press anything. It only shows that. The laptop should meet the system requirements. I also changed the boot order in the BIOS.

Comment: which key are you pressing to enter the BIOS? On my HP Elite Desk PC it is necessary to start pressing the `Esc` key constantly once it is turned on until it shows that it is entering the system menu.

Comment: I also press the Esc key constantly to enter the BIOS. That is not the problem, I can enter the BIOS normally and change settings there but when I try to boot from the usb drive it shows the "GRUB" text in the upper left corner and just refuses to do anything else.

Comment: Already checked that before, sadly didn't fix my problem